# Partitions created with Windows 7 disappear in Windows XP

Tags: windows, partitioning

I was running Windows 7 on a desktop computer for 2 years. Yesterday, I had to reinstall Windows. I installed Windows XP SP3, since I had issues with the Windows 7 license.

Windows XP installed properly, but after the installation, I found that it is not showing 3 partitions of my hard disk, which are logical partitions created in Windows 7.

I had a total of 7 partitions in Windows 7 created by third party tools. However, Windows XP is showing unpartitioned space of 171 GB out of the total 320 GB.

I searched the internet, and I found some information suggesting that this might be happening due to uninstalled SATA drivers.

How can I recover my partitions?

Comment: -1 although you might be freaking out, please rework your question to be more reader friendly (and I am not talking about maybe not-so-good english)

Comment: Windows XP does not support the dynamic disk you created.  You are going to have to install Windows 7, besides, you cannot upgrade to Windows 7 from XP.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting with a Linux CD. If you can see your files there, plug in an USB disk and copy
your files to it. Next time, do this before you reinstall operating systems.